# Collecting the output from a command in Windows from users that are not computer savvy

Tags: windows, command-line, email

I was wondering what is the easiest way to collect the output from a command in Windows from users that are not computer savvy.

E.g. For example, If I need to collect the output from ipconfig from 20 people, I would like to have something that allows them to do something like this:

```
ipconfig /all > mail name@domain.com
```

The users are not computer savvy and I can't make assumptions about what version of Windows they have installed (although I know they are all XP or post-XP)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a batch file which outputs the results to a text file, then ask them to send you the text file, or use the command-line FTP client to upload the text file somewhere. I put the file in the current directory the script is running from (`%cd%`) and named it `results_%computername%` so that when you get these various files you can tell which came from which computer.

```
@echo off
ipconfig /all > "%cd%\results_%computername%.txt"
```

You would then have to [create an FTP script](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/), which automates the process of uploading the file to an FTP server.

Comment: if you removed %CD%\  then wouldn't that ipconfig line still cause the file to be created in the current directory?

Comment: @barlop yes, it would I suppose.

Comment: This is a very good idea.  For some reason I always forget that windows has a command-line FTP utility.

Answer (score 3):

Windows does not have a built-in mail utility for the command line.  Barring access to all of these people's computers, most likely what you would have to do is ask them to run ipconfig /all > somefile.txt, and then manually mail you the contents of this file.  I realize that this might not be ideal for users who are not very savvy, but it is about the only way I can think of that doesn't involve installing custom software on each machine.

If, on the other hand, you have access to all of these machines, you could install a utility such as [bmail](http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm), and provide the users with the appropriate instructions.  Keep in mind you still need to provide it with an SMTP server/connection information, so you might need to throw together a batch file to keep your users from having to type all that out.

Answer (score 2):

This also might not be the greatest option in the world, but rather than having them run *ipconfig /all >somefile.txt* then trying to find that file and attach it to the e-mail, they COULD right click on the title bar of the command prompt window and go to *Edit --> Select All* then press *Enter* to copy all and then paste it into the body of an e-mail they could send to you.

Answer (score 0):

If their Internet connection's working fine, you could have them go [here](http://supportdetails.com/) and enter your email address there so they can send it to you. If you need more fine-grained details from CLI tools, then I think [nhinkle's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/283043/collecting-the-output-from-a-command-in-windows-from-users-that-are-not-computer/283097#283097) might be the best option.